# Highchart js Area chart Tooltip bug

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have been trying to clear this bug but i still not getting the point why it occurs.

check the code at http://jsfiddle.net/3RKL4/

The tool tip works only for the first and last points.

Is this a bug in highcharts or the code is wrong ?

If the code is wrong can any one help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally Highchart requires data to be increasing order of time. Your data doesn't seem to satisfy that, it doesn't work event with 3 points http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/3RKL4/5/
Reversing the order fixed it @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/3RKL4/6/