# Highcharts column range not sowing columns

Tags: highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/Sq9SL/2/

I think perhaps something is wrong with my Json data which is causing there to be no columns.

```
Can someone help me identity what the problem is please
```

Thank you

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797319/highcharts-strange-error-from-creation-of-stock-chart/11798546#11798546 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329044/highchart-js-area-chart-tooltip-bug/12329785#12329785

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the JSON needs to have the smallest number first

so a data value like

```
[1517443200000,123808,101168]
```

should be

```
[1517443200000,101168,123808]
```